# Best practice: try/catch two things in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I am developing a web application. The android wrapper has a JavaScript interface naming android and IOS has an Interface naming ios. I have to try both interfaces but only one of them will respond.

I don't know where to place the second try? inside the **first try**? inside **catch** or **finally** or **throw** or totally separated try/catch blocks?

Which one is logically preferred and which one is better in performance?

First Idea:

```
try {
    ios.myMethod();
    }

catch(err) {

            try {
                 android.myMethod();
                 }
            catch{
                 console.log('The Android does not exist');
                  }

            console.log('The ios does not exist');
        }
```

Second Idea:

```
try {

     try {
          android.myMethod();
          }
     catch{
         console.log('The Android does not exist');
          }

    ios.myMethod();
    }

catch(err) {
            console.log('The ios does not exist');
        }
```

third idea:

```
try {
    ios.myMethod();
    }

catch(err) {
            console.log('The ios does not exist');
        }
 finally{

      try {
          android.myMethod();
          }
      catch{
         console.log('The Android does not exist');
          }
       }
```

my last idea:

```
 try {
      android.myMethod();
      }
 catch{
     console.log('The Android does not exist');
      }

 try {
      ios.myMethod();
      }
 catch{
     console.log('The IOS does not exist');
      }
```

Comment: If you are sure that definitely one of them will respond, why are you checking for both?

Comment: Because it is a web based application and I dont know which device will use it

Answer (score 0):

The first idea seems appropriate. Also look if you can use if else statements instead like so:

```
if (window.ios && window.ios.myMethod {
    ios.myMethod();
} else if (window.android && window.android.myMethod) {
    android.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer the first method to others?

Comment: It is the only one that tries less things. Also finally is an antipattern in many cases in JavaScript, putting things after try catch is better